# Jquery Scroolbar Reverse on a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I'm trying to have the scroll-thumb on bottom of the window, and then when you scroll it up, the text inside the div will be scrolling down.
I've tried scrollTop(), but I'm always getting null or 0

It's a WordPress!

http://vega.targetmotion.com/vega-for-change/la-firma/

Many thanks!